# String not returning correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, return

First off, disclaimer that I'm new to C#. I'm trying to make the value of `wkflow_param` available to another project in the same Visual Studio solution, and then pass `wkflow_param` into a function in that other project. When I run the interpreter related to this code and get to `"return wkflow_param"`, I hover over it and it says `"wkflow_param = 'conceptual_manufacturing'` (This is the correct value, I have set it in another program).

If I switch to the second project and hover over `GeneratePostProcessingScript(wkflow_param)` it says `wkflow_param = 'conceptual_manufacturing'`, so I know that part is correct. However, after I pass this point and get into the other project, `wkflow_param` comes back as null - And I'm not sure why it switches all of a sudden

```
public partial class Interpreter
{
    private string ManufacturingGeneration(MgaFCO currentobj)
    {
            foreach (var wf_item in tb.Children.WorkflowRefCollection)
            {
                string TB_child_item_name = wf_item.Name;
                var workflow_item = wf_item.ReferencedBy;
                foreach (var task_item in wf_item.Referred.Workflow.Children.TaskCollection)
                    {
                        string TaskName = task_item.Name;
                        string wkflow_param = (task_item.Attributes.Parameters).ToLower(); 

                        return wkflow_param;
                     }
             }
     }
}
```

The other project's structure goes:

```
public partial class Interpreter : IMgaComponentEx
{
    public void InvokeEx(MgaProject project, 
                        MgaFCO currentobj, 
                        MgaFCOs selectedobjs, 
                        int param)
        {
            GeneratePostProcessingScript(wkflow_param);
        }
}
```

I've cut out a lot of the code as it's hundreds of lines, but I believe this is all the required information to tell what's been going wrong.

Comment: edit: I just realized the title isn't solid, I know it's working correctly, my code is what isn't.

Comment: the return statement should be after all the loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this statement

> return wkflow_param;

should come after the ending of

> foreach (var wf_item in tb.Children.WorkflowRefCollection)

Comment: To mention why, a return statement can be used as an Exit out of a method/function.  If you put it in the loop, you're asking it to exit every iteration - So it exits the first time, and doesn't continue to loop.

Comment: that returns an error that 'wkflow_param conflicts with the declaration of CyPhyPrepareIFAB.CyPhyPrepareIFabInterpreter.wkflow_param'? How should I alter the string wkflow_param = ... to accomodate this?

Comment: Just rename wkflow_param to something else as you are just using it as a temporary variable..

Comment: Success! Well, leads me to another question. Instead of "string wkflow_param = ....", I put "wkflow_param = ....", and then "return wkflow_param" at the end of the first for loop.

My question is why did that not return an error?  I came across it by accident as I was typing, I would have thought that it would return an error saying that wkflow_param wasn't declared.

Comment: Because you did not initialize another wkflow_param to confuse the compiler. You had used the earlier one(I guess you have declared it somewhere above not shown in the question)

Comment: aha. It had been defined in a separate project I hadn't seen before. Thank you.